# Where are these 14 GB images that are occupying my Android storage?

Tags: storage, oneplus-5t

I have been running out of storage on my android phone, the one plus 5T. I have Google photos backing up to the web and have deleted the local images post backup.

Google photos and even gallery are barely taking up a gigabyte.

But there under storage it does show 14 GB of images but I cannot seem to identify where these are or which app they belong to. I looked up all the usual culprits in the app list  but none of them shows  a claim to 14 GB of memory.

Any thoughts how I can find these images and reclaim the space?

[image]

Comment: For in-depth explanation see my answer to [How disk space is used on Android device?](https://android.stackexchange.com/a/216132/218526)

Comment: I deleted my answer since your issue is not related to Google trash (6 photos only) and the answer posted by Irfan above would probably help you to get to the root of it. You may see [this](https://android.stackexchange.com/a/223643/131553) if it helps. Thanks. All the best