# Need advice on deleting ".tmp" file in DCIM/Camera

Tags: file-management

The DiskUsage app shows that I have a 1/2 GiB file under DCIM/Camera, called something like 20160701_173401.tmp

DiskUsage will run HexEdit and show me the file...so I can see it's an mp4 video file, but since the filename suffix is ".tmp", it won't play it for me.

I'd like to get rid of the file ...
Unfortunately, DiskUsage also won't *remove* the file :(

The Camera app, and other apps aware of videos/images, can not "see" the file (or, said more precisely, it probably ignores it due to the ".tmp" suffix).  (I've also tried several "file explorer" type apps...no luck.)

The phone (Samsung Galaxy S7 Edge) is not rooted.

Is there a way to delete this file, short of resetting the entire phone?

I haven't tried yet, but am willing to write a special-purpose Solar2d (Corona SDK) app to "open" and "remove", but I'm not sure that's going to work.
...nope.  Did that, fails for "no permission".

BTW, full name of file is:
/storage/224B-18F6/DCIM/Camera/20160701_173401.tmp

thanks,

Stan

Comment: This [solution](https://android.stackexchange.com/a/223643/131553) is worth a shot

Comment: That points to the external SD card. You could simply shut down your phone, remove the card, put it into a card reader, attach it to your PC – and remove the file there. After that, put the card back into your Android device and power it up.