# My storage keeps increasing drastically despite not downloading anything and freeing up lots of space (4GB>200mb??)

Tags: internal-storage, storage, huawei, virus

I am using a Huawei P10 Lite.

This is absolutely insane and I desperately need a solution, I can't even begin to imagine what's causing this.

I've been getting the whole "storage space running out" message for a while now, so yesterday I went ahead and I ported 4GB worth of space to my SD card, leaving tons of free local space on my phone. The message dissappeared after this.

And yet today I suddenly get the same "storage space running out" message, I go look up the amount of storage I have in settings, and suddenly it says there's only 400mb left, and a few hours later now there's only 200mb left. How is this possible?? I freed up 4GB and now suddenly there's only 200mb left?? Something's very wrong here.

***I DID NOT DOWNLOAD A SINGLE THING IN THIS TIME PERIOD, NOT ONE THING***

Some things worth mentioning:
-I have auto-updates off, so that's not the issue here
-When I check my local folders it all amounts to about 5GB, not even close to 32GB which is the total internal storage of my phone
-I already uninstalled updates of built-in apps I don't use, it didn't change this problem
-I use Clean Master to delete cache and free up space, but it keeps increasing more and more regardless
-Due to certain circumstances I cannot do a factory reset right now and need a different solution

If there is any other information you need please don't hesitate to ask

This is a massive problem for me and I am desperate for any solution or just fidning the culprit behind this for that matter... thank you all very much for your attention.

Comment: Identify what's eating your space and try to recover. See [this Q&A](https://android.stackexchange.com/q/222396/131553) for both

Comment: moving stuff out of Android folder is pointless as everything will just recreated inside origin location, android doesn't know about your external MicroSD Card. if you think some app caused this, check your data usage statistics you will figure out which app. clear data of this app.

Comment: Some apps can create extremely large log files even from just running in background (usually if the developer for git to disable the verbose mode from development).