# Other storage taking over

Tags: storage, oneplus

My other storage has taken over my phone. I have factory reset it and cleared cache, removed unneeded apps. But still the other storage keeps increasing. I don't know what to do anymore.
I have a OnePlus 8T no older than 2 years.

Please help i am desperate.

[image: Screenshot of phone]

Comment: Try the app [mentioned here](https://android.stackexchange.com/a/223643/131553) // Since your storage is nearly full, you may need to uninstall a few apps to install this app

Comment: I cannot download anything new, nor can I delete anything.

Comment: Can you connect to PC, copy the images and videos to it and delete those from device//Also try to uninstall apps using play store. If that fails you can try to uninstall using `adb uninstall "package name` (for which you will need to install adb on your laptop) // Android prevents installation of new apps if 10% of memory is not free. That's why you first need to make space and then install the recommended app to try and reclaim storage//If nothing works for you and you are willing to lose all data then do a factory-reset