# Where does Whatsapp store its data on the phone?

Tags: whatsapp-messenger, storage, android-11

I was clearing up some storage in my phone. The File Explorer App says Whatsapp takes 10.68 GB (see screenshot 1), whereas the folder **Android/media/com.whatsapp** is only 6.23 GB (see screenshot 2). Is there any other place where Whatsapp stores its data?

I have a Xiaomi phone with MIUI 12.5 and Android 11 RKQ1.

---

[image]

---

[image]

Comment: No. My phone doesn't have any data in the locations listed in that answer, i.e. Android/data/com.whatsapp

Comment: Other folders listed in that answer don't exist on my phone. Probably because of the changes in data storage policies with Android versions.

Comment: That's the only location where it stores data. Two possibilities I can think of a) WhatsApp cache taking up unusually large space b) storage mis-reported. Double check with an app like [this](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.google.android.diskusage)

Comment: Another [alternative](https://android.stackexchange.com/a/223643/131553)

Comment: *"My phone doesn't have any data in the locations listed in that answer"* - yes for sure there is data in *'/data/user[_de]/<user_id>/<pkg>'* but you don't have root access